# Probability distribution; what is probability that i wont spend more than 75% of the customers

Tags: standard-deviation

Very simple question but I am kinda stuck.

Suppose that evidence in sales data suggests that average amount spent by a customer in a store averages 35.60 with a standard deviation of 16.4. A sample  of 64 customers is selected at random for study.

I cant figure out how to find answer to part D.

For part A,B,C I used

- mu=35.6

  n=64

  sigma=16.4

  Standard Error= 16.4/sqrt 64 = 2.05

  z=(x-u)/(q/sqrt of n)

  so x minus mu over Standard error (sigma over sqrt of n).

If you guys could help me check that my answers are right?

**A**. What is the probability that the sample mean of the amount spent exceeds 38.00?

Answer:z= 38-35.6/2.05 = 1.171; P(0.1210=12.10%)

**B**. What is the probability that the sample mean of the amount spent is between 35.00$(x1) and 38.00$(x2) ?

z of x1 = -0.293; P = 0.3859

z of x2 = 0.195; P = 0.4247

1-(0.3859+0.4237)= 0.18936

**C**. What is the probability that the sample mean of the amount spent is no more than 34.00?

z= -0.78; P(0.2236)

**D. what is the maximum you are willing to spend if you dont want to spend more than 75% of the customers?
I dont know how to do this one.**

I am prepping for exam and this question is taken directly out of past ones. If anyone has sometime to help with some questions it would really mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part A is correct.

Part B has the wrong z value for $x_2$. It should be the same you had before, 1.17. But the method is correct.

Part C has the wrong p value for $z=-0.78$. Check the tables.

For part D you are considering the distribution of X (a typical shopper) and not the sample mean, so use $SD=16.4$. First you need the z value corresponding to the upper quartile, approx $0.675$

Then, $$0.675=\frac{X-35.6}{16.4}$$

Find $X$

I hope this is OK! Good luck with the exam.

Comment: thank you, got to ask how come you didnt use SD/sqrt of n for part D and just used SD=16.4?

Comment: P.S I made a mistake in part B when i was copying it, its 36 not 38.